# How to debug "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page"?

Tags: wp-admin, permissions

The error `You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page` when trying to access `wp-admin` can result from many causes. How can I debug effectively what is causing the problem?

Is there any extended error log?

Comment: This may help: https://codelight.eu/analyzing-not-sufficient-permissions-access-page-error-wp-admin/